# How can I dynamically add to a JavaScript object similar to JavaScripts array push function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add to the data.data.trek.places object.  For example, if a user triggers an event I want to add to this object and then be able to iterate over it again, but I'm not sure how to do it. I couldn't find something similar to the push function with arrays.  My app sits on top of backbone, maybe there is an underscore function for this?

I essentially want to do:

```
data.data.trek.places.push({
                            "url" : "/attraction/mauna-kea-summit/19",
                            "img_src" : "http://trekeffect.images.user_images.s3.amazonaws.com/4_36.jpg",
                            "title" : "Mauna Kea Summit",
                            "time_going" : "1368787333",
                            "time_going_hour" : 1,
                            "time_going_minutes" : 55,
                            "duration" : "3600",
                            "id" : 19,
                            "type" : "attraction",
                            "city_id" : 6
                           });
```

The json I have coming from the original ajax is below:

```
{
  "data":{
  "trek":{
     "places" : [
        {
           "url" : "/attraction/mauna-kea-summit/19",
           "img_src" : "http://trekeffect.images.user_images.s3.amazonaws.com/4_36.jpg",
           "title" : "Mauna Kea Summit",
           "time_going" : "1368687333",
           "time_going_hour" : 1,
           "time_going_minutes" : 55,
           "duration" : "3600",
           "id" : 19,
           "type" : "attraction",
           "city_id" : 6
        },
        {
           "url" : "/attraction/mauna-kea-resort-golf-course/20",
           "img_src" : "http://trekeffect.images.user_images.s3.amazonaws.com/4_41.jpg",
           "title" : "Mauna Kea Resort Golf Course",
           "time_going" : "1368704533",
           "time_going_hour" : 6,
           "time_going_minutes" : 42,
           "duration" : "5400",
           "id" : 20,
           "type" : "attraction",
           "city_id" : 6
        }
     ]
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

`data.data.trek.places` **is** an array.
It's exactly like any other array, except that it happens to be referenced by a property of an object.

You can use it just like any other array.